# how to add logo to fixed navigation in T3 template

Tags: php, joomla, navigation, fixed

I have adjusted my mainnav.php file in the T3 template for joomla so my navigation is fixed to the top of the page. However, I cannot figure out how to add my logo to the left of my fixed navigation?

```php
<!-- MAIN NAVIGATION -->
<nav id="t3-mainnav" class="wrap navbar navbar-default t3-mainnav navbar-fixed-top navbar-collapse-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">

        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">

            <?php if ($this->getParam('navigation_collapse_enable', 1) && $this->getParam('responsive', 1)) : ?>
                <?php $this->addScript(T3_URL.'/js/nav-collapse.js'); ?>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".t3-navbar-collapse">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
            <?php endif ?>

            <?php if ($this->getParam('addon_offcanvas_enable')) : ?>
                <?php $this->loadBlock ('off-canvas') ?>
            <?php endif ?>

        </div>

        <?php if ($this->getParam('navigation_collapse_enable')) : ?>
            <div class="t3-navbar-collapse navbar-collapse collapse"></div>
        <?php endif ?>

        <div class="t3-navbar navbar-collapse collapse">
            <jdoc:include type="<?php echo $this->getParam('navigation_type', 'megamenu') ?>" name="<?php echo $this->getParam('mm_type', 'mainmenu') ?>" />
        </div>

    </div>
</nav>
<!-- //MAIN NAVIGATION -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add logo div before `<div class="container">` and float both divs left like:

```
#t3-mainnav .logo_container,
#t3-mainnav .container {
  float: left;
}
```

Hope this helps